# How to create Jenkins SSH key in Linux for use with Github?

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh-keys

At the moment, I'm trying to configure an SSH key to use for cloning Github repositories into a Jenkins pipeline.  When I login to my Linux server as the Jenkins user and attempt to create a SSH keypair, below is the output I get:

```
-bash-4.2$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: Permission denied
```

Do I need to elevate my privileges in order to create these keys?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  When running the ssh-keygen command, it likes to create the .ssh directory on its own.  I had created it ahead of time and that clearly created some sort of permissions issue.

So in the future: if you're ever creating these keys and getting a permissions error, allow the command to create the .ssh directory to avoid any issues.  Thanks.

Comment: Just for clarification: 
If a ~/.ssh directory already exists, then you will need to rm -rf .ssh FROM INSIDE
/var/lib/jenkins/
Then  you will be able to execute the ssh-keygen and ENTER at all the prompts.